# Do instant and sorcery cards reach the graveyard before their effects go on the stack?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

For example, will a [Lightning Strike](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=447288) kill a [Haunt of Hightower](http://mythicspoiler.com/rna/cards/thehauntofhightower.html?fbclid=IwAR0PBogzIf6wblze8KCP8shQHq4mfyzYyKqwo003_0vJc2cSRPFCLLzVyjY) that just came out?

Comment: But short answer to your question, ya it dies.